# Como usar condicionais no cmd como diferente de?, maior igual a...?

Tags: windows, cmd, prompt

Comecei recente a treinar uns scripts no prompt de comando do windows (cmd), mas na hora que fui usar a condicional "IF" tive umas dúvidas, no caso queria saber como usar a condicional "if" no sentido de "if" %talcoisa% for diferente de %talcoisa2% e %talcoisa3% goto para "tentar de novo".
Já tentei analisar o comando "if /?" mas não entendi muito do que era pra fazer, vi que tinha q usar um tal de "NEQ", mas ainda não entendi como utilizar tal comando. Vou disponibilizar o comando no qual estava tentando para que possam entender o que estou precisando.
A parte que preciso estou deixando entre '#'

```
@ECHO OFF

TITLE Teste de escolhas do Daniel

ECHO Para fazer o teste de comandos, e necessario responder algumas perguntas antes

    PAUSE
    CLS

ECHO vamos la, para isso iniciarei com algumas perguntas basicas

    PAUSE
    CLS

:R.Tentardnv
    
ECHO -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
ECHO 1 isso e um bloco de notas?
ECHO 2 isso e um prompt de comando?
ECHO 3 negao, nao sei nao
ECHO -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

SET /P escolha= Entao, qual a sua resposta? :

# IF %escolha%!= 1,2 or 3 GOTO R.Tentardnv #
IF %escolha%==1 GOTO R.Errada
IF %escolha%==2 GOTO R.Certa    
IF %escolha%==3 GOTO R.Tentardnv

:R.Invalida
ECHO resposta invalida, tente novamente
GOTO R.Tentardnv

:R.Errada
ECHO e negao nao foi dessa vez
GOTO END

:R.Certa
ECHO boa, era essa mesmo
GOTO END

:END
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1):

- Comparações numéricas para `integer == integer`:

```bath
if número EQU 1 (
     ação número = 1
   ) else if número EQU 2 (
     ação número = 2
   ) else if número EQU 3 (
     ação número = 3
   ) else (ação número diferente de 1, 2 e 3)
```

**Obs:** Números sempre inteiros

---

- Usando comparações numéricas onde:

```bath
if número NEQ 3 (
    ação número != 3
   )

if número EQU 3 (
    ação número == 3
   )

if número GEQ 3 (
    ação número >= 3
   )

if número LEQ 2 (
    ação número <= 2 
   )

if número GTR 3 (
    ação número > 3 
   )

if número LSS 2 (
    ação número < 2 
   )
```

---

- Portando para seu script:

```bath
if %escolha% EQU 3 goto R.Errada
if %escolha% EQU 2 goto R.Certa
if %escolha% EQU 1 goto R.Tentardnv
goto R.Tentardnv   // :: se todas acima forem false :: //
```

---

- Portando para seu script em um só laço `if () else if() else ()`

```bath
if %escolha% EQU 1 (
     goto R.Errada
   ) else if %escolha% EQU 2 (
     goto R.Certa
   ) else if %escolha% EQU 3 (
     goto R.Tentardnv
   ) else ( goto R.Tentardnv )
```

---

- Comparações `string == string`

```bath
If not "string” == "%Var_String%" (
     ação case sensitive  string != %Var_String%
   ) else if /i not "StRiNg" == "%Var_String%"
     ação case insensitive StRiNg != %Var_String%
   )
```

---

- Referências:
  [`if /?` |  SS64.com /en-US](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
  [`if /?` | Microsoft Docs /pt-BR](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/if)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo